# Javascript function not being called when I navigate to a page in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a simple jQuery Mobile app, essentially 2 pages.

The first page has a single button:

```
  <a href="location.html" data-theme="b" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Create Report</a>
```

When a click on the button I navigate to `location.html`, this page has its own JS file and inside that file is the following:

```
(function( $, undefined ) { 
    $( document ).on( "pageshow", function(){
        initMap();
    });
})( jQuery );
```

However when I reach the page the JS function `initMap();` is not called, if I refresh the page the function is called but not when I navigate using the button on the home page.

How can I ensure this function is called each and everytime I navigate to this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have an ID for  your `location.html` page. something as below

```
<div data-role="page" id="location">
</div>
```

change your js file's contents as below

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#location', function(){
   initMap();
});
```

now this should invoke the function every time you visit the page.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try with this

```
pageScript(function($context){
  $context.bind("pagecreate", function(event, ui) {
    initMap();
  });
});
```

check more functions here

http://markdalgleish.com/2011/04/document-ready-for-jquery-mobile/